# Check if destructor is destroying all the dynamic memory?

Tags: c++

Is it any way in c++ to check if dynamic allocated memory is deleted after the destructor is called? As far as I am concerned, it is not possible to access the memory after the object. So how do I check that the memory is removed from the freespace 
Example:

```
//main file
#include <iostream>
#include "kake.h"

using namespace std;

void test() {
    Kake kjeks(2);
    Kake cookie(kjeks);
    cookie = kjeks;
    cout << kjeks.getDynMem() << endl;
    cout << cookie.getDynMem() << endl;
}


int main() {
    test();
    //Is the memory gone?
    return 0;
}

//Kake class declaration
class Kake {
public:
    Kake();
    Kake(int ant);
    ~Kake();
    Kake(const Kake& rhs);
    Kake& operator=(const Kake& rhs);

    int getAntall()const { return antall; }
    int getDynMem() const { return *dynMem; }
    int * getDynAddr() const { return dynMem; }

private:
    int antall;
    int *dynMem;
};

//Kake implementation
#include "kake.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Kake::Kake():antall(0){}
Kake::Kake(int ant):antall(ant){
    dynMem = new int;
    *dynMem = 2;
}
Kake::~Kake(){
    delete[] dynMem;
}
Kake::Kake(const Kake& rhs):antall(rhs.antall){
    dynMem = new int(rhs.getDynMem());

}
Kake& Kake::operator=(const Kake& rhs){
    dynMem = new int;
    *dynMem = rhs.getDynMem();
    antall = rhs.antall;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `delete[] dynMem;` is UB, since it was allocated with `new int;`

Comment: "Is it any way in c++ to check if dynamic allocated memory is deleted after the destructor is called? " Not really. There are other tools, [valgrind being a popular and effective one](http://valgrind.org/), used to detect memory leaks.

Comment: Don't use dynamic memory unless you need to.  When you do, use `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool to do this is valgrind. Valgrind is a hugely useful tool for checking for memory leaks.

Do something like

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck your_program_name
```

This will run your program and you will be able to compare the number of memory allocations to the number of memory freed. This will give you a good idea of if you are leaking memory